# Is this code(js) correct?...if yes then why everytime i run this code my browser crashes

Tags: javascript

```
//coding practice 
let items = prompt();

while (true) {
  items;
  if (items === "STOP") {
    break;
  }
}

let itemList = [items];

console.log(itemList);
```

Comment: No, it is not correct. You only prompt for the "items" value once, and so if it's not `"STOP"` the loop will never stop and the browser will kill it.

Comment: because the loop runs forever, I assume you want the prompt in the loop.

Comment: When prompted, do you enter the string "STOP"?  If not then you have an infinite loop.  (And if so then what's the point of the loop at all?  You can effectively replace all of this code with simply: `console.log(["STOP"]);`)

Comment: You probably need something like this: `let list = []; while (true) { let item = prompt(); if (item === "STOP") break; else list.push(item) }` Add the prompt value to a list until the user types `STOP`

Comment: You expect to call `prompt` when you write `items` but that will not happen. It is just another variable that has the value you enter in first prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Putting prompts inside loops is not the right way to quiz until the answer satisfies. Better to use recursion through a function - prompt, then recurse if the answer isn't right, like:

```js
function getItems() {
  let items = prompt();
  if (items === "STOP") return items;
  return getItems();
}
let itemList = [getItems()];

console.log(itemList);
```

Answer (score 1):

`items` is not a function, rather the result of prompt(). You want to call it *in* the loop:

```js
let itemList = [];
while (true) {
  let value = prompt();
  itemList.push(value);
  if (value === "STOP") {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(itemList);
```